# Agents connection not restricted to one type of agents in AnyLogic

Tags: connection, anylogic, agent

I have a rectangular node where 30 people and 5 facility randomly located. I wanted to create distance-based connection among people only. On the main tab, I did- Network type: Distance-based, Connection range:70. On the Person tab, Agent type: Person and turn on "Draw line". So, what I got (attached figure), it's not only create connection among people but also with facility within that distance range. But I want to create connection only among people. How can I do it?[connection output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygf4Z.png)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to ensure that your Person agents are only connected to other persons.

Do not use the default `Connections` object to manage agent connections. Create custom "Agent link" objects, one `Person.conn_MyOtherPersons` and another `Person.conn_MyBuildings`.

Then only animate `Person.conn_MyOtherPersons`

Check the example models and tutorials for learning more about agent connections, they are very powerful to use.

Comment: Hi Benjamin - Thank you so much for giving hints. I have created a function, which is working perfectly what I wanted. I am providing that function in the following Answer, so that anyone facing the same question can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working perfectly to solve the above described problem. I have created this function in main and call it on startup.

```js
for (int i=0; i<people.size(); i++){
    Person p=people.get(i);
    for (int j=i+1; j<people.size(); j++){
        Person q=people.get(j);
        if (people.get(i).distanceTo(people.get(j))<100)
            p.connectTo(q);
    }
}
applyNetwork();
```

Comment: cool. But you are still using the default agent connections. In the future, you will want to use custom Agent links to split your connection types :)

Thx for sharing the answer :)